# Is there something wrong with my learning curve or my model because it starts at the end of tail completely opposite?

Tags: machine-learning, learning

[image]

Hello,

Would be nice if you could review my graph and tell me if there is something wrong or not. The context is that it uses a MLP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with the image.